# Why do Poisson regression and negative binomial regression give totally different results?

Tags: glmm, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I have data on blue sheep density in 55 survey units which are watersheds. I want to test what factors affect blue sheep density. I used blue sheep count data in each watershed, and log(area of the watershed) as an offset. Since the 55 watersheds are distributed in 7 different sites far away from each other to represent different livestock density, I used GLMM to include site as a random effect.

```
library(lme4)
# Negative Binomial Regression
M1 <- glmer.nb(BS~s.AGB+log(s.DEM)+sqrt(s.VRM)+s.LS+sqrt(s.HOUSE)+sqrt(s.ROCK)+
             log(s.Viewshed)+(1|Site)+offset(log(Area)),data=bs)
summary(M1)
# Poisson Regression
M2 <- glmer(BS~s.AGB+log(s.DEM)+sqrt(s.VRM)+s.LS+sqrt(s.HOUSE)+sqrt(s.ROCK)+
          log(s.Viewshed)+(1|Site)+offset(log(Area)),data=bs,family=poisson)
summary(M2)
```

"s.coefficient" means scaled coefficients. I've re-scaled all the X variables into the range of 0-10.

The results given by the two models are very different. M1 gives no significant effects at all, and lots of convergence warning. Whereas M2 shows almost all the variables are significant.

```
**Summary M1:**
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace     Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: Negative Binomial(0.4529)  ( log )
Formula: BS ~ s.AGB + log(s.DEM) + sqrt(s.VRM) + s.LS + sqrt(s.HOUSE) +       sqrt(s.ROCK) + log(s.Viewshed) + (1 | Site) + offset(log(Area))
Data: ..2

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
552.7    572.8   -266.3    532.7       45 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.7843 -0.6953 -0.3354  0.2942  4.5536 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
Site     (Intercept) 2.460e-12 1.569e-06
Residual             7.353e-01 8.575e-01
Number of obs: 55, groups:  Site, 7

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     -0.4162880 19.7722023  -0.021    0.983
s.AGB            0.0043793  0.4259805   0.010    0.992
log(s.DEM)       0.1617608  8.4140466   0.019    0.985
sqrt(s.VRM)     -0.0059249  0.5631603  -0.011    0.992
s.LS             0.0008908  0.1290667   0.007    0.994
sqrt(s.HOUSE)    0.0037029  0.3077675   0.012    0.990
sqrt(s.ROCK)     0.0093700  0.7265202   0.013    0.990
log(s.Viewshed)  0.0070697  0.8106204   0.009    0.993

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) s.AGB  l(.DEM s(.VRM s.LS   s(.HOU s(.ROC
s.AGB       -0.453                                          
log(s.DEM)  -0.973  0.250                                   
sqrt(s.VRM) -0.410  0.180  0.392                            
s.LS         0.124 -0.198 -0.077 -0.317                     
sqr(.HOUSE)  0.071 -0.320 -0.003 -0.423  0.130              
sqrt(.ROCK)  0.032  0.749 -0.239 -0.131 -0.043 -0.202       
lg(s.Vwshd) -0.120  0.119  0.024 -0.091 -0.234 -0.064  0.149

**Summary M2:**
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace  Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: BS ~ s.AGB + log(s.DEM) + sqrt(s.VRM) + s.LS + sqrt(s.HOUSE) +       sqrt(s.ROCK) + log(s.Viewshed) + (1 | Site) + offset(log(Area))
Data: bs

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
3293.1   3311.2  -1637.5   3275.1       46 

Scaled residuals: 
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-9.888 -5.417 -1.435  5.447 24.053 

Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Site   (Intercept) 0.6708   0.819   
Number of obs: 55, groups:  Site, 7

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -48.22938    3.53361 -13.649  < 2e-16 ***
s.AGB            -0.02396    0.03920  -0.611 0.541081    
log(s.DEM)       21.36638    1.63916  13.035  < 2e-16 ***
sqrt(s.VRM)      -0.20076    0.06962  -2.884 0.003929 ** 
s.LS             -0.19084    0.01227 -15.557  < 2e-16 ***
sqrt(s.HOUSE)     0.43643    0.03284  13.290  < 2e-16 ***
sqrt(s.ROCK)     -0.38330    0.10476  -3.659 0.000253 ***
log(s.Viewshed)   1.91979    0.09484  20.242  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) s.AGB  l(.DEM s(.VRM s.LS   s(.HOU s(.ROC
s.AGB        0.221                                          
log(s.DEM)  -0.990 -0.322                                   
sqrt(s.VRM) -0.318 -0.274  0.349                            
s.LS         0.314  0.103 -0.323 -0.231                     
sqr(.HOUSE) -0.570 -0.318  0.583 -0.014 -0.092              
sqrt(.ROCK)  0.731  0.668 -0.795 -0.523  0.311 -0.373       
lg(s.Vwshd) -0.536 -0.043  0.500 -0.225 -0.200  0.170 -0.302
```

The two models are nested so normally will produce quite similar results. Why in my case could the results be opposite?

Comment: Can you give the output of summary(M2)?

Comment: I've added "Summary M1" and "Summary M2" as headlines in the results just now.

Comment: Little time now, for the poisson regression the problem probably is overdispersion, the deviance given is 3275.1 on residual df=46, indicating huge overdispersion. The significance you obtain from the poisson model is then based on the (very) untrue Poisson assumption that variance=expectation, in reality your variance is way bigger. Do glmer have a quasipoisson family? if so, you should try it.

Comment: Thank you Kjetil for your suggestion. If overdispersion is the problem, then negative binomial would also be suitable to use? I'm searching for the convergence warnings and found this page: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html. Now I'm guessing that the random effect (site) I added is causing the problem. The results of M1 shows site has the variance of 2.460e-12 (very close to zero). I deleted the random effect (site) in M1 and got two significant fixed effects and no warning. However is this the true reason and how to explain this?

Answer (score 2):

For the poisson regression the problem probably is overdispersion, the deviance given is 3275.1 on residual df=46, indicating huge overdispersion. The significance you obtain from the poisson model is then based on the (very) untrue Poisson assumption that variance=expectation, in reality your variance is way bigger.

Do glmer have a quasipoisson family? if so, you should try it.